# What kind of coord-sys is this? - 955999.8911220022, 26397850.011872

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates

How can I identify this coordinate system? When I load the .shp with QGIS I get the correct linear mapping. However when I try to convert to GeoJSON and plot with something like Leaflet.js I get nothing. These coordinates exist roughly around: 35.161066,-114.576794

[(955999.8911220022, 26397850.011872), (955998.9291220009, 26397799.942871995), (955998.9461220019, 26397798.020871997)]

Comment: Have you tried doing, in QGIS, a right click on the layer, then `layer properties` and at last `information`?

Comment: I have now - Geometry: Line(MultilineString); CRS: EPSG:3421 - NAD83 / Nevada East (ftUS) - Projected; Extent: 955736.6651220023632050,26397765.5478719994425774 : 957601.4161220006644726,26397850.0118720009922981

can I convert this to lat/long coodinate or similar mapping for use in something like leaflet.js?

Comment: The default CRS for GeoJSON is 4326

Comment: You could use those coordinates in Leaflet, but how, that's for a different focused question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is some version of State Plane Nevada East with measurements in feet. For example, choosing ESRI:102707 from the EPSG database (http://epsg.io/102707) yields coordinates in that range near 35.16 N lat, -114 W long.

Note that there are several alternative specifications of the State Plane Nevada East projection, so if you don't get the exact one, your coordinates may be off by a couple of meters. But the one I referred to is *probably* the most common if the original data source was, say, an ESRI shapefile.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be EPSG:3421. `(955999, 26397850)` translates to Lat 35.1612555° Lon -114.5801733° at epsg.io.

When looking for projected CRS on the basis of given coordinates, I'm using [SHPProjFinder](https://github.com/maegger/SHPProjFinder) tool. This is local Java program, based on similar algorihms as [projfinder.com](http://projfinder.com/), but with much improved efficieny.